# Sorting Char Vector

Tags: c++, string, vector, char

I'm a trying to convert an imputed string of characters in to a vector in Cstring and get them sorted . I have everything work except when I create the string the last word inserted just get repeated. I know its around this area

```
while(getline((text), words, ' '))
    spliter.push_back(words.c_str());
```

that my code messes up so I wondering if any one could tell me where I'm going wrong and can fix it. I know a regular C++ string would be more efficent however it has to be done this way and I;m kinda lost

```
{ const int limit  =301;

 char input[limit];
string words;

 characters

cin.getline(input, limit);


words =input;

vector <const char*> spliter;

stringstream text(words);

 while(getline((text), words, ' '))

        spliter.push_back(words.c_str());

        for(auto x:spliter) cout << x << " "; cout << endl ;

    auto cstr_compare = [](const char* s1, const char* s2) {

        return strcmp(s1,s2) < 0; };

    sort(spliter.begin(), spliter.end(), cstr_compare);

    for(auto x:spliter) cout << x << " "; cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: Why are you using `char*` in the vector instead of a `std::vector<std::string>`? You won't need to provide your own comparison function then.

Comment: First of all, there is no "char vector" in the code you show, but there is a vector of *pointers* to `char`. Secondly, *why* do you have a vector of pointers instead of a vector of `std::string`?

Comment: You should really use correct indentations. I'ts a bit hard to read your code.

Comment: ... perhaps a *vector of `char`* would fit the usecase better?

Comment: The code is formatted kind of higgledy-piggledy and hard to follow.

Comment: As for your problem,you make *all* pointers point to the string in `words`, a single variable. And there's really no guarantee that it will kepp that memory, if it reallocates due to a longer string than the capacity then all previous pointers becomes stray and invalid. What you have is a classic case of [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: "I have everything work", he writes... "`characters cin.getline(input, limit);` is a perfectly cromulent expression!", he writes...

Comment: Could you please just tell me if the solution I proposed was of any help for you?

Comment: Thank you very much it solved my issue perfectly! It was a really good example to learn from and study . Thank you once more.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you this solutions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void ctokenize(const stringstream& text, vector<const char*>& tokens)
{
    std::string::size_type pos = 0;
    std::string::size_type lastPos = 0;

    string str = text.str();

    while(std::string::npos != pos) {
        // find separator
        pos = str.find(" ", lastPos);

        // Found a token, add it to the vector.
        string strFound = str.substr(lastPos, pos - lastPos);
        tokens.push_back(strdup(strFound.c_str()));

        // set lastpos
        lastPos = pos + 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int limit = 301;
    char input[limit];
    string words;

    //characters

    cin.getline(input, limit);

    words = input;

    vector<const char*> spliter;

    stringstream text(words);

    /*
    while(getline((text), words, ' ')) {
        spliter.push_back(words.c_str());
    }
    */

    ctokenize(text, spliter);

    for(auto x:spliter) {
        cout << x << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    auto cstr_compare = [](const char* s1, const char* s2) {
        return strcmp(s1,s2) < 0;
    };

    sort(spliter.begin(), spliter.end(), cstr_compare);

    for(auto x:spliter) {
        cout << x << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```